# Creating a RAM disk out of an existing folder on a hard drive

Tags: memory, ramdisk

I know there's a lot of software that will allow you to create a RAM disk, but I have a specific situation.

I'd like to put my installation of League of Legends onto a RAM disk. The issue is that League of Legends, in Windows, points to an exact location within C:\ in many instances of the program. That being said, it cannot be installed on a separate drive.

How can I set it to create a RAM disk out of an existing folder on C:\?

Comment: See last bullet point on page http://superuser.com/help/on-topic

Comment: Im scratching my head on this.  Why do you want to do this?  LoL is a fairly lightweight game.  Yes, by doing this the game would *load* faster, but once in game there would be no benefit.

Comment: @DaveRook I don't agree that this is necessarily a **product recommendation** question. The OP is asking **how to accomplish a goal;** it seems to me that any RAM disk driver would be equally good (or bad) to do this. Now, *why* one would do it is a different matter, but doesn't really change whether this is a product recommendation question or not.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling, if you look through the edit history you'll see it was quite specifically a software recommendation, and this is when I posted my initial comment. If the mods want to remove my initial comment as it's no longer needed, fine.

Comment: @DaveRook No, I considered the question as it currently is, not as it once was. I see now that it once was a product recommendation question, but it doesn't appear to be any longer.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a RAM disk then copy/move the content of the LoL folder to it. Rename or delete (make sure the RAM disk software is set to save it to disk if so) the LoL folder.

You can then create a symlink (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Symlink) to the RAM disk by executing the command (with a few adjustments) below in a command prompt.

```
mklink /j "C:\path\to\LoL" "R:\"
```

R: would be the RAM disk drive letter